# Is there a difference when registering an IHostedService in .NET Core 3.+ in the startup.cs ConfigureServices or in program.cs Main method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm playing around with trying to use IHostedServices in a 3.1 .NET Core web application.

I can see that I can register them in 2 different places:

- `program.cs`

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<BackgroundServiceA>();
            services.AddHostedService<BackgroundServiceB>();
        });
```

or in the `ConfigureServices` method in `startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHostedService<BackgroundServiceA>();
}
```

I'm under the impression that both of these are identical. And if they are, does one override the other, if both exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm under the impression that both of these are identical.

Yes, both approaches inject a delegate into the logic used to build an `IServiceProvider`. Whether you do this via the `IHostBuilder` or the `Startup` class, the result is the same.

> Does one override the other, if both exist?

The answer to this depends on two things:

1. The order in which you've registered the delegates.
2. The details of the registration itself.

To make it easier to explain, here's the code copied from your question:

> ```
> public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
>     Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
>         .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
>         {
>             webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
>         })
>         .ConfigureServices(services =>
>         {
>             services.AddHostedService<BackgroundServiceA>();
>             services.AddHostedService<BackgroundServiceB>();
>         });
> ```

> ```
> public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
> {
>      services.AddHostedService<BackgroundServiceA>();
> }
> ```

This shows an order that goes like this:

1. `Startup.ConfigureServices`, because `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` is called first.
2. `IHostBuilder.ConfigureServices`

This means the registration in your `Startup` class runs first; followed by the registration performed via `IHostBuilder.ConfigureServices` in the `Program` class.

If you switch the order of those two calls, you also switch the order of the registrations:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<BackgroundServiceA>();
            services.AddHostedService<BackgroundServiceB>();
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

With this change, the registration performed via `IHostBuilder.ConfigureServices` runs first.

`AddHostedService` uses `TryAddEnumerable` behind the scenes. If `TryAddEnumerable` is called with a `TService` to `TImplementation` pair that already exists in the service collection, it's ignored. Consider the following example, slightly adapted from the code in your question:

```
services.AddHostedService<BackgroundServiceA>();
services.AddHostedService<BackgroundServiceA>();

services.AddHostedService<BackgroundServiceB>();
```

The first call to add `BackgroundServiceA` succeeds, registering `BackgroundServiceA` against the `IHostedService` interface. The second time it's called, nothing happens, because this pair has already been registered.

The first call to add `BackgroundServiceB` also succeeds. Although this is using the same interface, `IHostedService`, it's a different implementation that's being registered, and so it's a different pair.

All of this means that the registration in your `Startup.ConfigureServices` is the one that will be used. This is because it runs first *and* because later registration ends up as a no-op.